# JSF 2.0 @ViewScoped losing data

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, richfaces, myfaces

The main situation is that i have a @ViewScoped that works as a @RequestScoped.

Atm, i have a view that contains a List of items with a @RequestScoped bean behind. When i want to update one of this items i navigate to a view with a @ViewScoped behind.

When i do a post from this view, i come back to the list view and the @ViewScoped gets destroy. so far, so good.

The problem is that, when i am updating the view with the @ViewScoped bean, all the bean's attribute are null. Its looks like a @RequestScoped.
Also i have a @PostConstruct method that is call every time and it shouldn't.

In the view with the @ViewScoped i make use of the followng tags: h:selectOneMenu , rich:fileUpload , a4j:repeat , a4j:ajax , h:commandLink in all over the code.

I didn't not put the full code as is a big form what i have.

I have not clue what's happening as it was not happening this before. If need more info pls ask.

Regards.

edit:

When i execute a method that makes a post (its saves the item's data on DB) the bean has all the data. But when i want to obtain data from it is when the bean is empty.

Example:

```
<h:outputLabel value="#{locale.link}:" />
                <h:inputText value="#{newsBean.newsLink}"
                    disabled="#{not newsBean.editPage}" />
                <h:link value="#{newsBean.newsLink}" target="_blank"/>
```

When i press on the link, the bean is empty so i get null pointer to the item "news".

Comment: Related: [The benefits and pitfalls of @ViewScoped](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2010/06/benefits-and-pitfalls-of-viewscoped.html)

Comment: Did you check all [this](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#ViewScopedFailsInTagHandlers) problematic tags for view scoped bean?

Comment: what do you mean by "when i am updating the view"? you use ajax in the page, and after ajax method calls bean is re constructed? maybe you could show snippet of some of these ajax calls so we can take a look. also, are the imports of the ManagedBean and ViewScoped classes ok?

Comment: @partlov: i am using ui:composition and looks like doesnt work with this.

Comment: It should work, except when you have some el in attributes for ui:composition, ui:include or ui:decorate

Comment: Where is the method in the backing bean that issues the POST? Are you returning a String outcome from it?